# How to read in a file name using command line and args?

Tags: java, command-line, readfile, args

My instructions state:

> Main gets the file name from the command line (i.e., `args[0]`).

I am just pretty clueless on how to approach this. I have put the text file in the same folder as my code and then my first attempt was just to the set my `String fileName = args[0]`. That did not work and do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Please be more specific what didn't work and add code and errors to the question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and expound on "did not work".

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please define "did not work" (since that'll work; it stores the command line parameter into a string variable).

Comment: How did you run your program??

Answer (score 0):

For passing Args to your java code you need to run it like this [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

```
java MyApp arg1 arg2
```

If you are using an IDE for running your application search for the documentation how to pass args to your java Code for example this is for [idea](https://users.drew.edu/bburd/JavaForDummies6/CommandLineIntelliJIDEA.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your command line looks like:

```
MyApp arg1 arg2 arg3
```

In our java code:

```
arg[0] == "MyApp arg0 arg1 arg2"              (the whole command line)

arg[1] == "arg1"

arg[2] == "arg2"

arg[3] == "arg3"
```

More specific to your problem, your file name will be in `arg[1]` if it is the first command line parameter.

Comment: So do I need to set arg[0] equal to my file name? or is the file name automatically placed in the array list and I am just calling the wrong position of the array?